Issues with saving token in the database and using private key to sign JWT tokens in Flask
I'm encountering some issues with implementing authentication in a Flask application. I need help understanding why my token isn't being saved in the database and why my private key isn't working correctly to sign JWT tokens.
I'm using Flask with PostgreSQL to store user data and generate JWT tokens for authentication. However, when attempting to save the token in the database after user registration, it doesn't seem to be stored correctly. Additionally, when trying to sign JWT tokens with my private key, it appears that the signing isn't being done correctly.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
# Relevant code snippet

# Function to generate token
def generate_token(username, email, expiration_time=20):
    # Load the private key
    with open('private_key.pem', 'r') as f:
        private_key = f.read()
        
    payload_data ={
        'username': username,
        'email': email,
        'exp': int(time.time()) + expiration_time
    }
    token = jwt.encode(
        payload=payload_data,
        key=private_key,
        algorithm='RS256',
    )
    
    return token

# Route for user registration
@user_bp.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
    # Extract json data from HTTP request using the get_json() method of the request object
    data = request.get_json()
    # Check if all mandatory fields are filled, if not return error
    required_fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password']
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in data or not data[field]:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Field {field} missing or empty!'}), 400

    username = data['username']
    email = data['email']
    password = data['password']
    confirm_password = data['confirm_password']

    if password != confirm_password:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Passwords do not match!'}), 400

    try:
        conn = connect_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Check if username and email of the user already exist in the database, if so return error
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s OR email=%s", (username, email))
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Username or email already exists!'}), 400

        # Encryption before insertion into the database
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())

        # Creation of JWT token
        expiration_time = 20  # Token expiration time in 20 seconds 
        token = generate_token(username, email, expiration_time)
        print("token before inserting into db:", token)
        # Insert the new user into the database
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password,token) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
                       (username, email, hashed_password.decode('utf-8'), token))
        new_user = cursor.fetchone()
        print("token before inserting into db:", token)
        conn.commit()

        if new_user:
            user_data = {
                'id': new_user[0],
                'username': new_user[1],
                'email': new_user[2],
                'token': new_user[3]
            }
            
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Error retrieving user data after registration!'}), 500

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
    finally:
        if 'conn' in locals():
            conn.close()
    return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'User registered successfully!'}), 201


image database
When running this code, the token seems to be generated correctly, but it's not being stored in the database. Additionally, when trying to use the private key to sign JWT tokens, it seems that the signing isn't done correctly.
I appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve these issues.
Thank you.

Hello, I'm concerned about the length of the generated JWT token. Specifically, the token length is determined by the payload containing the username and email. I'm worried that the combined length of the username and email could exceed the maximum token length allowed in the database.

Where do you check if there is even a token generated? The INSERT statement is executed successfully, looks like "token" is NULL.

@FrankHeikens yes, the token is being saved as null, I have already set it to print the token before and after the database insertion time, but it is not printed in the terminal or in the database

@fabelx How would I check this?

There is no token generated, you now have to find out what goes wrong in your function

comment try except block code to check token. There are no issue on saving token. The token is none is this case and the length jwt token will over 100 length as your field in db only config length 100
